# Constant times a random variable and the relation with the binomial distribution

Tags: statistics, random-variables, binomial-distribution

My question is really simple:

> If $X$ is a random variable with $m\cdot X\sim Bin(n,p)$ what can
> I say about $X$?

I'm trying to find a binomial distribution which X is similar to. In another words, I'm trying to find $k,l$ such that $X\sim Bin(k,l)$. I've tried to solve it but I can't find the link between the multiplication of the constant to the $X$ and the PMF of the binomial.

Comment: Do you need to find the distribution of $Y=mX, X\sim Bin(n.p)$?

Comment: @АлександрПальма yes!

Comment: A binomial random variable has possible values $0,1,2,\ldots,n$.  If you divide it by $m$ then it takes the different values $0, \frac1m,\frac2m,\ldots, \frac nm$.  You can say $X$ has mean $ \frac nm p$ and variance  $ \frac n{m^2} p(1-p)$

Comment: @АлександрПальма - I had read the question as $Y \sim Bin(n,p)$ and $mX=Y$

Comment: @Henry but when we divide by $m$, $X$ is not well defined, no? for example, if $m=2$, 1/2 isn't in $X\sim bin(n,p)$, I've just realized that.